# Android Studio - How to create a back button on randomly selected strings?

Tags: android, arrays, button

I have an array of strings that I am displaying in my activity using a random number every time a button called **Next** is clicked. How do I create another button called **Back**, that simply displays the previously or last generated strings in the order they were randomly generated?. So that instead of clicking next to generate another string, I can click **Back** at any time to view all the previous strings one by one and then click **Next** again to continue the random selection.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some of the relevant code as a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)? We need a little more to answer your question, but then we'll be able to send you in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: So far, I have my MainActivity as:

https://s3.postimg.org/n7kteqkcj/one.jpg

I therefore need to create some kind of listener on the BackButton.
The getFunFact method in my other java file is:

https://s22.postimg.org/84eedk5bl/two.jpg

Comment: Please read about the definition of the SO "random" and "numbers" tags and remove them from your question. It is very annoying for people who look for questions with these tags to find questions that have absolutely no connection to these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Create a array list of String like

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
```

after that using add function add the strings that you are displaying in your activity using a random number every time a button called Next is clicked.

```
 arraylist.add("your_randomly_generated_string");
```

now your randomly generated string will stored in arraylist one by one 
This will store the string now how to retrieve?
following steps may help you not sure ...
While adding the randomly generated string into arraylist initialize the int variable with zero and increment its value after each adding...

```
public int indexvalue=0;
```

on your Onclick of NEXT button add two lines

```
arraylist.add("your_randomly_generated_string");
indexvalue++;
```

And now on the Onclick of BACK Button Use indexvalue to retrieve...

```
String data = arraylist.get(indexvalue);
indexvalue--;
```

here Decremented the indexvalue to retrieve the previous string..
hope you'll understand what im trying to say little bit of lengthy explanation ...

Comment: Thanks Ashish. I did understand your explanation. It works.